# Devise Master Account

Tags: ruby, user-controls, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am making a website for me and my friends to organise games online.  I am using Rails 3 and Devise.  I was basically wanting to be able to login to the accounts of other users without needing a password to do this.  I looked at using a authorization gem list CanCan but this is not really what I am looking for.

It would be in a sense session switching.  Has anyone done this before with Devise?  If I have not explained it well please let me know.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an action that does this:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter authenticate_user!

  def become
    return unless current_user.is_an_admin?
    sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
    redirect_to root_url # or user_root_url
  end
end
```

More info on Devise's wiki entry about it https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin

Answer (score 0):

You really *do* want something like CanCan for this, I think. Why do you think you don't?

Regardless, you're going to want to store roles for your users.

Comment: Hi, I came to the realisation of this when I went implement it :)